# How do i fix Session Fixation in PHP

Tags: php, session, cakephp

How do i fix Session Fixation in PHP/cakephp. I am on a shared host.

EDIT
i am on a shared host how can i enable it if i dont have aces to php.ini

Answer (score 6):

- Set [session.use_only_cookies=true](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies).
  It's harder with cookies than POST/GET parameters to inject and/or social-engineer a session id.
- Set [session.cookie_httponly=true](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly). Not really because of session fixation but session hijacking  ...anyway, there shouldn't be a good reason for a client-side script to be able to read the session id cookie.
- Use [session_regenerate_id()](http://docs.php.net/session_regenerate_id) as often as you deem necessary; at minimum every time a login is attempted.

Comment: i am on a shared host how can i enable it if i dont have aces to php.ini

Comment: Both session.use_only_cookies and session.cookie_httponly are markes as PHP_INI_ALL. I.e. you can set the values via ini_set(), before you call session_start(), _every time_ before you call session_start().

Comment: If you are using mod_php in apache you should be able to set php values in .htaccess files, ex: php_value  upload_max_filesize  2M